# Why updating consumption horizon for several Twilio IPM channels fails?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I have several open Twilio IP Messaging channels in my webapp. And then I'm trying to update consumption horizon using `updateLastConsumedMessageIndex` for several open channels sequentially. I handle the Promise returned by `updateLastConsumedMessageIndex` by handling `.then`, and channel data in `then` handler indicates that requests is not fulfilled cause channel's lastConsumedMessageIndex is still the old one.

The issue can be fixed by calling `updateLastConsumedMessageIndex` recursively until consumption horizon is updated.
Example code:

```
function updateChannelConsumptionHorizon (channel) {
  let lastMessageIndex = channel.messages[channel.messages.length - 1].index
  channel.updateLastConsumedMessageIndex(lastMessageIndex).then(channel => {
    if (channel.lastConsumedMessageIndex !== lastMessageIndex) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        updateChannelConsumptionHorizon(channel)
      }, 100)
    }
  })
}
```

Interesting fact, first call to `updateChannelConsumptionHorizon` does not require more than one attempt, whereas subsequent calls make up to 60 attempts to update the consumption horizon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio throttles updates to consumption horizon, and it is sent to server every 10 seconds by default. Use [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/rest/services) to update `consumption_report_interval`

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you!